# Module MapboxGeocoder not found Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox, swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to install the MapboxGeocoding framework with Cocoapods and Xcode9. Unfortunately Xcode can't find the module. It shows me the following error: Cannot load underlying module for 'MapboxGeocoder'

The pod file looks as the following:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

    target 'FrameworkTest' do
      # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift', '~> 0.7'

      # Pods for FrameworkTest

    end
```

I checked also the build settings of the Xcode Project. It looks like the following:
[Framework Search Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R402x.png)

Finally nothing worked for me. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

PS: The normal MapBox Framework works well with cocoapods

Comment: Make sure that you are adding pod, not in the test framework. Is this your project name?

Comment: Yes, that's the name of my project!

Comment: try adding $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)/YourProjectFramework folder in Framework search path

Comment: I tried your approach but unfortunately I couldn't import the module. I tried with the following: $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods but it couldn't load. Has someone another idea?

Comment: Now I could solve the issue. I tried your configuration again and built the application. Although the error was showing, after building the app the error went away.

Comment: Happy , that error has been resolved, I will post the same as an answer so that you can mark this question as answered.

Comment: I tried the above approch as my project is in Objective-c. But its not working. Use this framework instead.Its working https://github.com/tingslabs/TIMapboxGeocoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your framework header search path is missing this path. Try adding `$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(PROJECT_DIR)/YourProjectFramework` folder in Framework search path

Hope this helps you!